# HighChart's Pie Chart Labels Don't Evenly Distribute Around Chart & Downloaded Image Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

I would like my labels to distribute evenly around my chart but they are left aligned for some reason. I inspected the element in Chrome and all but one of them of them are in an absolute position approximately 25px from the left. Also, when I downloaded the image of what it currently looks like, the image shows what appears to be overlapping labels. This is not visible while on the web page, and I'm not sure why they are in the image. Here is my code and an image.
[image]

```
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        plotBorderColor: '#0574AC',
                        borderWidth: .5,
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 55,
                            beta: 0
                        },
                        renderTo: 'buRequests',
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'YTD Requests by ATO'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}' + ' Requests' + '<br>' + '{point.percentage:1.0f}%'
                            //percentageDecimals: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: false,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            depth: 35,
                            dataLabels: {

                                softConnector: true,
                                useHTML: true,
                                enabled: true,
                                fontWeight: 'medium',
                                //format: '{point.name}'+ '<br>' + '{point.y}' +' Requests' + '<br>' + '{point.percentage:1.0f}%',
                                formatter: function() {
                                    var req;
                                    if (this.point.y === 1) {
                                        req = " Request";
                                    } else {
                                        req = " Requests";
                                    }
                                    return '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + this.point.name + '<br>' + this.point.y + req + '<br>' + Math.round(this.percentage) + '%' + '</span>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'BU Count',
                        data: chartData,
                        colors: ['#F9B112', '#EB6E00', '#42C5F1', '#0472A9', '#C1D52C', '#4AA70A']
                    }],
               });
```

Comment: At this moment this is default datalabels positioner, but you can [wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) our functions by API and create your won.

Comment: That sounds great. Do you have an example of that? I want my chart to look like this http://jsfiddle.net/6afyH/1/ and I can't see where an API was used.

Comment: At this moment we have no this kind of algorithm, but you can prepare your own logic.

Comment: ok, thank you. Also, I am using V4.1.7 and I rolled back to V3.0.1 and it fixed the image issue. There may be a bug in your code.